# How to prevent re-render of child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have a problem with rerendering child component.

I have two components:

**Parent:**

```
const Parent = () => {
    const { checkAuth } = useActions();
    const { isLoading } = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);

    useEffect(() => {
        checkAuth();
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loader />;
    }

    return (
        <Child />
    );
};

export default Parent;
```

**Child:**

```
const Child = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Child Component
        </div>
    );
};

export default Child;
```

Action checkAuth() causes the isLoading change in authReducer. So, after isLoading changes, Child component re-renders.

How can I prevent re-render of Child component in this case?

Comment: What is the "case"? When parent re-renders?

Comment: isLoading changes in Parent and this causes Child re-render

Answer (score 2):

> How can I prevent re-render of Child component in this case?

If you are not passing any props to this `Child` (especially functions), wrapping child with `React.memo` is enough. This will provide *shallow* comparison which will prevent the re-render.

```
const Child = React.memo(() => { ... });
```

Comment: I've tried it but Child is still re-rendered.

Comment: @Aliaksei No, if you are not passing any props to `Child` and wrapped with `memo`, it will not re-render.

Comment: @Aliaksei BTW, make sure to disable StrictMode if you are using it. StrictMode causes the component to render twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having one single return in the parent component?

```
const Parent = () => {
    const { checkAuth } = useActions();
    const { isLoading } = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);

    useEffect(() => {
        checkAuth();
    }, []);

    return (
    <div>
      {isLoading
        ? <Loader />
        : <Child />
      }
    </div>
    );
};

export default Parent;
```

And of course, you should follow @kind user's input and use React memo for your Child component:

```
const Child = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Child Component
        </div>
    );
};

export default React.memo(Child);
```